# Providing typeclass instance for all MonadTrans instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

I've defined my own monad transformer:

```
data Config = Config { ... }

data State = State { ... }

newtype FooT m a = FooT {
      runFoo :: ReaderT Config (StateT State m) a
    } deriving (Functor, Monad, MonadReader Config, MonadState State)
```

And I've defined a `MonadTrans` instance for it.

```
instance MonadTrans FooT where
   lift = FooT . lift . lift
```

Now, I have various monads that I can't just have be derived for me by the compiler. I'll take `MonadIO` as the example. So I've defined my `MonadIO` instance as

```
instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (FooT m) where
    liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

However, I find that I'm doing a lot of lifting, for each Monad. Why could the author of each Monad typeclass (i.e. MonadIO, MonadCatchIO, MonadFoo) not define a general instance in terms of MonadTrans, instead of making me implement an instance for each new MonadTrans I come up with? a la

```
instance (MonadIO m, MonadTrans t, Monad (t m)) => MonadIO (t m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

That requires `UndecidableInstances` to compile, and I'm not certain that it's correct (in fact, pretty sure it's incorrect), but serves to express my intent for now.

So, is this possible? If not, why not? Will it ever be?

Comment: I haven't fully understood that topic, but the problem seems to be that different monads have different "lifting" capbilities. The [layers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/layers) package tries to approach these difficulties, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that I've come up with an alternative to [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html), called
`MyMonadIO`.  It's like `MonadIO` in every way, except for the name:

```
class Monad m => MyMonadIO m where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

Assuming your `FooT` type:

```
newtype FooT m a = FooT
  { runFoo :: ReaderT Config (StateT AppState m) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Config, MonadState AppState)
```

It's possible to create an instance of `MyMonadIO` for [`ReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:ReaderT),
[`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT), and finally `FooT`.  I've added extra type annotations to make it
easier for the reader to figure out what's going on:

```
instance MyMonadIO m => MyMonadIO (ReaderT r m) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> ReaderT r m a
  myLiftIO = (lift :: m a -> ReaderT r m a) . (myLiftIO :: IO a -> m a)

instance MyMonadIO m => MyMonadIO (StateT s m) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> StateT s m a
  myLiftIO = (lift :: m a -> StateT s m a) . (myLiftIO :: IO a -> m a)

instance MyMonadIO m => MyMonadIO (FooT m) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> FooT m a
  myLiftIO = (lift :: m a -> FooT m a) . (myLiftIO :: IO a -> m a)
```

It's also possbile to use [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) to easily derive
`MyMonadIO` for `FooT` (assuming there are already instances for `ReaderT` and
`StateT`):

```
newtype FooT m a = FooT
  { runFoo :: ReaderT Config (StateT AppState m) a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MyMonadIO, MonadReader Config, MonadState AppState)
```

---

If you look at the body of the `myLiftIO` function for the `ReaderT`, `StateT`,
and `FooT` instances, they are exactly the same: `lift . myLiftIO`.

Here's a repeat of the question:

> Why could the author of each Monad typeclass (i.e. MonadIO, MonadCatchIO,
>   MonadFoo) not define a general instance in terms of MonadTrans, instead of
>   making me implement an instance for each new MonadTrans I come up with?

For `MyMonadIO`, this general instance would be as follows:

```
instance (Monad (t n), MyMonadIO n, MonadTrans t) => MyMonadIO (t n) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> t n a
  myLiftIO = (lift :: n a -> t n a) . (myLiftIO :: IO a -> n a)
```

With this instance defined, you don't need a specific instance for `ReaderT`,
`StateT`, or even `FooT`.

This requires `UndecidableInstances`.  However, the problem with this is not undecidability, but that this instance overlaps some potentially valid instances of `MyMonadIO`.

For instance, imagine the following datatype:

```
newtype FreeIO f a = FreeIO (IO (Either a (f (FreeIO f a))))

instance Functor f => Functor (FreeIO f) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> FreeIO f a -> FreeIO f b
  fmap f (FreeIO io) = FreeIO $ do
    eitherA <- io
    pure $
      case eitherA of
        Left a -> Left $ f a
        Right fFreeIO -> Right $ fmap f <$> fFreeIO

instance Functor f => Applicative (FreeIO f) where
  pure :: a -> FreeIO f a
  pure a = FreeIO . pure $ Left a

  (<*>) :: FreeIO f (a -> b) -> FreeIO f a -> FreeIO f b
  (<*>) (FreeIO ioA2b) (FreeIO ioA) = FreeIO $ do
    eitherFa2b <- ioA2b
    eitherFa <- ioA
    pure $
      case (eitherFa2b, eitherFa) of
        (Left a2b, Left a) -> Left $ a2b a
        (Left a2b, Right fFreeIOa) -> Right $ fmap a2b <$> fFreeIOa
        (Right fFreeIOa2b, o) -> Right $ (<*> FreeIO (pure o)) <$> fFreeIOa2b

instance Functor f => Monad (FreeIO f) where
  (>>=) :: FreeIO f a -> (a -> FreeIO f b) -> FreeIO f b
  (>>=) (FreeIO ioA) mA2b = FreeIO $ do
    eitherFa <- ioA
    case eitherFa of
      Left a ->
        let (FreeIO ioB) = mA2b a
        in ioB
      Right fFreeIOa -> pure . Right $ fmap (>>= mA2b) fFreeIOa
```

You don't necessarily need to understand this `FreeIO` datatype (especially the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances).  It's enough just to know that this is a valid data type.

(If you're interested, this is just a [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) wrapped around `IO`.)

It's possible to write a `MyMonadIO` instance for `FreeIO`:

```
instance Functor f => MyMonadIO (FreeIO f) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> FreeIO f a
  myLiftIO ioA = FreeIO (Left <$> ioA)
```

We can even imagine writing a function using `FreeIO`:

```
tryMyLiftIOWithFreeIO :: Functor f => FreeIO f ()
tryMyLiftIOWithFreeIO = myLiftIO $ print "hello"
```

If you try to compile `tryMyLiftIOWithFreeIO` with both this instance (`MyMonadIO (FreeIO f)`) and the bad instance from above, you get the following error:

```
test-monad-trans.hs:103:25: error:
    • Overlapping instances for MyMonadIO (FreeIO f)
        arising from a use of ‘myLiftIO’
      Matching instances:
        instance (Monad (t n), MyMonadIO n, MonadTrans t) => MyMonadIO (t n)
          -- Defined at test-monad-trans.hs:52:10
        instance Functor f => MyMonadIO (FreeIO f)
          -- Defined at test-monad-trans.hs:98:10
    • In the expression: myLiftIO $ print "hello"
      In an equation for ‘tryMyLiftIOWithFreeIO’:
          tryMyLiftIOWithFreeIO = myLiftIO $ print "hello"
```

Why does this happen?

Well, in `instance (Monad (t n), MyMonadIO n, MonadTrans t) => MyMonadIO (t n)`, what is the kind of `t` and `n`?

Since `n` is supposed to be a `Monad`, it's kind is `* -> *`.  And since `t` is a monad transformer, it's kind is `(* -> *) -> * -> *`.  `t n` is also supposed to be a `Monad`, so it's kind is also `* -> *`:

```
n :: * -> *
t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
t n :: * -> *
```

Now, in `instance Functor f => MyMonadIO (FreeIO f)`, what are the kinds of `FreeIO` and `f`?

`f` is supposed to be a `Functor`, so it's kind is `* -> *`.  `FreeIO`'s kind is `(* -> *) -> * -> *`.  `FreeIO f` is a `Monad`, so it's kind is `* -> *`:

```
f :: * -> *
FreeIO :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
FreeIO f :: * -> *
```

Since the kinds are the same, you an see that `instance Functor f => MyMonadIO (FreeIO f)` overlaps with `instance (Monad (t n), MyMonadIO n, MonadTrans t) => MyMonadIO (t n)`.  GHC isn't sure which one to pick!

You can get around this by marking your instance `FreeIO` instance as `OVERLAPPING`:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Functor f => MyMonadIO (FreeIO f) where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> FreeIO f a
  myLiftIO m = FreeIO (Left <$> m)
```

However, this is a treacherous route to go down.  You can find out more about why overlapping can be bad from the [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-overlap).

This `FreeIO` example was created by Edward Kmett.  You can find another clever example of an overlapping instance in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5zjwym/when_is_undecidableinstances_okay_to_use/deynhlx/?utm_content=permalink&utm_medium=front&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=haskell).

---

If you are planning on writing a monad typeclass (like `MyMonadIO`) and
releasing it to Hackage, one option is to use the
[`DefaultSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures)
functionality. This makes it easier for users of your library to define
instances.

Using `DefaultSignatures`, defining the `MyMonadIO` class would look like this:

```
class Monad m => MyMonadIO m where
  myLiftIO :: IO a -> m a
  default myLiftIO
    :: forall t n a.
       ( MyMonadIO n
       , MonadTrans t
       , m ~ t n
       )
    => IO a -> t n a
  myLiftIO = (lift :: n a -> t n a) . (myLiftIO :: IO a -> n a)
```

This says that there is a default implementation of `myLiftIO` for any `t n`,
where `n` is an instance of `MyMonadIO`, and `t` is an instance of
`MonadTrans`.

With this default siguature for `myLiftIO`, defining instances of `MyMonadIO` for `ReaderT` and `StateT` would look like this:

```
instance MyMonadIO m => MyMonadIO (ReaderT r m)
instance MyMonadIO m => MyMonadIO (StateT s m)
```

Very simple.  You don't need to provide the function body of `myLiftIO` since
it will use the default.

The only drawback of this is that it is not widely done.  The
`DefaultSignatures` machinery seems to be mainly used for [generic
programming](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generic-programming), not monad typeclasses.